# Is there a ppa from which to install caine linux tools on Ubuntu?

Tags: ppa

There is this linux distro called caine linux (computer aided investigative environment) which is required for a computer forensics course. It's Ubuntu based, and like most of these distros, I suspect there is a ppa from which to install its tools on Ubuntu without time overhead.

Comment: Looks like it's a distro all by itself. It doesn't seem to be available as a ppa.

Comment: @DKBose And even it was available via PPA,I would be very cautious about installing it. Countless people have completely screwed up their system by installing `katoolin`...

Comment: I think any installation of debian deb files (which kali is based on) on ubuntu is likely to brick something, hence the broken systems that used katoolin. However I'm taking about an ubuntu based distro here, I think I will just have to download the deb files and install them manually.